# Block all iframes from loading and replace with some text

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to block all iframes on a webpage from loading and replacing them with some text.

Any idea?

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
  var iframe = iframes[i];
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = 'Hello, I\'m an iframe';
  iframe.parentNode.replaceChild(div, iframe);
```

But it seems this only works for the first iframe. If i console log the number of iframes found it shows the actual number.

If i have 2 iframes it only works for the first, when i have 3 iframes it works for the first and the last.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is "live", it always reflects the _current_ state of the DOM. So when you remove the first iframe, the second one moves to index position 0; but your for loop in the next iteration will access index 1 - and therefor _skip_ an element. You could loop over it backwards, then you would not have that problem; or use `querySelectorAll` instead in the first place - that one returns a _static_ NodeList, so the changes you make to the DOM in your loop, won't affect what the variable `iframes` contains.

Comment: Yes that seems to work by using the querySelectorAll ! Thanks that really helps

Comment: `while (iframes.length) { const iframe = iframes[0]; .... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` is "live", it always reflects the *current* state of the DOM. So when you remove the first iframe, the second one moves to index position 0; but your for loop in the next iteration will access index 1 - and therefor skip an element.

You could loop over it backwards, then you would not have that problem; or use `querySelectorAll` instead in the first place - that one returns a *static* NodeList, so the changes you make to the DOM in your loop, won't affect what the variable `iframes` contains.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's not a good idea to remove elements from web pages so as not to affect layout etc, but you can always modify or hide them.

So there are many solutions to your requirement...

**1.** In your loop you can set the iframe source to "about:blank":

```
iframes[i].src='about:blank';
```

**2.** Or you can set the srcdoc itself to your personal message like this...

```
iframes[i].srcdoc='<html>My replacement message</html>';
```

**3.** And/or you can make the iframe disappear without wrecking the page...

```
iframes[i].style.visibility='hidden';

iframes[i].style.display='none';

iframes[i].style.zIndex='-2147483647';
```

And so forth...